# How to set default parameter inside a class?

Tags: python, class, oop, default-parameters

I'm creating a Binary Search Tree and I want to implement inorder traversal using recursion for which I need to pass in root value which in this case is `self.root`.

```
class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def inOrder(self, root):
        if root == None:
            return
        self.inOrder(root.left)
        print(root.data, end=" ")
        self.inOrder(root.right)
```

How do I pass `root`'s default value to be equal to `self.root`?
If I use:

```
class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def inOrder(self, root = self.root):
        if root == None:
            return
        self.inOrder(root.left)
        print(root.data, end=" ")
        self.inOrder(root.right)
```

It shows error that `self is not defined`.

Answer (score 2):

Even if this were possible, it would not be a good idea. The objects used as default arguments are set when the code is first interpreted, *not* each time the method is called. That means `self.root` must exist when the code is first interpreted, and every time the default argument is used, it would be referencing the original `self.root` object; not whatever `self.root` happened to be when the method was called. It is for this reason that you should really *never* have a mutable object as a default argument. Multiple calls to a functions all using the same mutable default argument leads to [wonky, erroneous behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument/11416002).

The typical workaround option is to default to `None`, then check on that:

```
def inOrder(self, root=None):
    if root is None:
        root = self.root
    . . .
```

Unfortunately, that won't work here because `None` has a special meaning in your function. You could instead use a sentinel object:

```
sentinel = object()  # A unique object

. . .

def inOrder(self, root=sentinel):
    if root is sentinel: 
        root = self.root
    . . .
```

Or, you could alter your program so that `None` is not a valid argument into that method, then use `None` instead of `sentinel`.